# Converting between date formats in R?

Tags: r, datetime

I have a data.frame (CSV originally) in R with dates are in the following 3 formats:

```
2011-06-02T17:16:05Z

2012-06-02T17:16:05-07:00

6/2/11 17:16:05
```

which is year-month-day-time. I don't quite know what the -07:00 is, as it seems to be the same for all timestamps (except for some where it is -08:00), but I guess it's some type of time zone offset.

I am not quite sure what format these are (does anyone know?), but I need to convert it to this format:

```
6/2/11 17:16:05
```

which is year-month-day-time

I would like to do this in such a way so that all the dates in the CSV (in one and the same row) is converted to the second format. How can I accomplish this in R?

The full dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/aronlindberg/VOSS-Sequencing-Toolkit/blob/master/rubinius_rubinius_sequencing/input.csv).

Comment: That's [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) time.  The "T" separates the date from the time.  It's not 16:05, it's 17:16:05 (05 is the seconds, not minutes).  The -07:00 is the offset from GMT

Comment: Thanks, I updated the question. Does this mean that the answers below are wrong?

Comment: Your link to the full dataset in broken

Comment: The times in that file don't look anything like what you've shown in this Q

Comment: Forget to update git repo, it is done now. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another attempt, assuming your data is text to start with:

```
test <- c("2011-06-02T17:16:05Z","2012-06-02T17:16:05-07:00")
format(as.POSIXct(test,format="%Y-%m-%dT17:%H:%M"),"%m/%d/%y %H:%M")

[1] "06/02/11 16:05" "06/02/12 16:05"
```

Comment: The data can be found here: https://github.com/aronlindberg/VOSS-Sequencing-Toolkit/blob/master/rubinius_rubinius_sequencing/rubinius-since-2011.csv

Comment: @AronLindberg - if it works on 2 cases, it'll work on 11,000. Just replace `test` with `dataframename$created_at`

Comment: Thanks. How do I apply this to a CSV file?

Comment: I have problems applying this to my code, since I also have events in the end which are coded as: "6/2/11 17:16:05". Can your code accomodate this as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, where `myDates` would be the column of dates

```
format(strptime(myDates, format="%Y-%m-%dT17:%H:%M"), format= "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
[1] "06/02/2011 16:05" "06/02/2012 16:05"

or with 2-digit year

# Note the lower-case %y at the end
format(strptime(myDates, format="%Y-%m-%dT17:%H:%M"), format= "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
[1] "06/02/11 16:05" "06/02/12 16:05"
```

As for the `Z`, that indicates GMT (think: London).
the `-7:00` indicates 7 hours back from GMT (think: Colorado / MST etc)

Please see [here](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/info/zulu.htm) for more reference

Comment: Will this delete the Z and -7:00 that occurs unevenly in the data?

Comment: Yes, it will delete it and does not take time zone into account

Comment: This makes me wonder, what are the advantages/disadvantages of `as.POSIX...` vs. `strptime`? Our answers are nigh on identical but using slightly different functions.

Comment: In general, I use strptime when converting from characters.  but that [is a very good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13813160/posix-vs-strptime).

Comment: I have problems applying this to my code, since I also have events in the end which are coded as: "6/2/11 17:16:05". Can your code accomodate this as well?